# Adding Numbers Using Recursion In C

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    int add(int n);

    void main()
    {
      int n, ans;
      clrscr();
      printf("Enter Number:");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      ans = add(n);
      printf("%d", ans);
      getch();
    }

    int add(int n)
    {       
      if (n==0)
      {
        return 0;
      } else { 
        return n + add(n-1);
      }
    }
```

I have some doubts related recursion programs which have this type of return statements. Can anyone explain me it in a proper way.
I am not able to understand that thing if I am writing return 0 when n==0 then why it returns value from else.Why answer is not 0.I am confused in return statement.
Plz help me.
Thank You In Advance.

Comment: First you say C, then you say C++. And don't tell me you _actually_ format your code in this manner?

Comment: Why would you do this using a recursive function at all?

Comment: _" I am not able to understand that thing if I am writing return 0 when n==0 "_ Well, the recursion needs to stop at some point, no?

Comment: It is useless to add 0, so you can stop the recursion at if ( n == 1 ) return 1 ;

Comment: Recursion can be reimplemented using stack as there is sth like call stack. First you are going all the way up to n == 0 and then all the way back using already returned result. Maybe this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Unwinding will be of some help to you.

Comment: You could try putting `printf("%d\n", n);` at the start of the `add` function, so you can see what is happening. The function sums the values from `n` down to `1`. So `add(5)` will return `15`.

Comment: Thank you. Specially Weather Vane it was really useful for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a simple example: `add(2)`.

In that initial call we go to the `else` branch (because `n` is not zero) and do `return 2 + add(2 - 1)` (i.e. `return 2 + add(1)`).

That leads to the second calls, which also goes to the `else` branch and does `return 1 + add(1 - 1)` (i.e. `return 1 + add(0)`).

That leads to a call in which `n` is equal to zero and so we return zero.

That returns to the `return 1 + add(1 - 1)` part, which is equal to `return 1 + 0` so return that.

That returns to the `return 2 + add(2 - 1)` part, which now is equal to `return 2 + 1`.

And that takes us back to the initial call, giving the result `3`.

---

It can be laid out in a tree something like

```
add(2) -> return 2 + add(2 - 1)
  add(1) -> return 1 + add(1 - 1)
    add(0) -> return 0
  add(1) -> return 1 + 0
add(2) -> return 2 + 1
```

Comment: I understood this thing but I am nit getting that where it will return the value..

Comment: @KeyurShah Learn how to use a debugger (you need to do it sooner or later anyway) and step through the code line by line, stepping into the recursive calls. See where the code goes, see the values of `n` change, see the return values. It should hopefully help.

Comment: @KeyurShah No, it always return to the *previous* call to `add`. A third way of seeing it might be something like `add(2) -> add(1) -> add(0)`, when you reach `add(0)` the function does `return 0` and it goes back up the call chain in the reverse order.

Comment: So after if statement it will return statement to add(2 and then add(2) and then it will be returned to main() ..Is this right..

Comment: sry..writing mistake.. 
So after if statement it will return statement to add(1) and then add(2) and then it will be returned to main() ..Is this right